# Select custom post by meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

Say I've got the custom post type `foo` with a meta box called `bar`. I've posted an entry with `bar` = `pineapple`. Now I want to check if there is a `foo` in the database with a `bar` set to `pineapple`. How would I do that?

I've managed to get this working using a `wpdb` query but that doesn't feel right. Is there an elegant, maybe built-in way for me to do this?

Comment: so the post meta key is `bar` and it's meta value is `pineapple`?

Comment: @birgire Yes, in 1 post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean a query like this one:

```
$args = array( 
               'post_type'      => 'foo', 
               'meta_key'       => 'bar', 
               'meta_value'     => 'pineapple',
               'posts_per_page' => 1,
        );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can check out further information [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) on *meta queries* in `WP_Query`.

If you only want to check if there exists such a post, you can use the `found_posts`  property:

```
if( $query->found_posts > 0 ){
    // do stuff
}
```

or the usual way with the `have_posts()` method:

```
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    // do stuff
}
```